# When to use Ø for states in DFA / NFA

Tags: theory, automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

I am confused about the usage of "Ø" in the DFA / NFA ( Let's talk about this in the context of DFA to NFA conversion )

Let's say that I have a NFA as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz5IQ.png)

There isn't any transition defined for symbol "a" for state 1. So in the transition table would i write the transition for the same as "Ø" or do i write "1" cause it will stay in state "1" as there isn't any transition arrow for it

So would it be this:

```
|      state     |     a    |   b   |    E    | 
|----------------|----------|-------|---------|
|          1     |     Ø    |  {2}  |   {3}   |
|          2     |   {2,3}  |  {3}  |    Ø    |
|          3     |    {1}   |   Ø   |    Ø    |
```

or:

```
|      state     |     a    |   b   |    E    | 
|----------------|----------|-------|---------|
|          1     |    {1}   |  {2}  |   {3}   |
|          2     |   {2,3}  |  {3}  |   {2}   |
|          3     |    {1}   |  {3}  |   {3}   |
```

The choice to use "Ø" affects the final output. Now, we could construct the power set of the states and then calcualte epsilon clousure, but let's cut it short, we will directly Let's look at a controversial state that may or may not be present in the final DFA, and we will try experiment using "Ø" and not using "Ø"

(1) Not using null: ( Table 2 )

State = {1,2}

From 1 and 2, on receiving a we go to 1,2,3

epsilon closure (1,2,3) = 1,2,3

(2) Using null: ( Table 1 )

State = {1,2}

From 1 and 2, on receiving a we go to {2,3}

epsilon closure (2,3) = 1,2,3

Now, the transition might look same but in some cases we would end up again with states where we don't have anywhere to go but to stay in the same state and if we choose to use "Ø" then we would have an additional state in the final output "Ø". In this case, it just means that if we don't have a transition for some symbol then we go to this state

But if we don't then our final output won't have the extra state "Ø". Here we don't specify the transition arrow for some symbol if we don't a transition for it, just like as for symbol "a" in state 1, in the diagram

So, which one is correct, one without the state "Ø" or one with the state "Ø"

Comment: A finite automaton will not 'stay' in a state unless there's a looping edge for that state.  Any symbol for which a state has no outgoing edge has an implicit edge from that state to an error/fail state (which is a non-accepting state that only loops to itself on all inputs).

Comment: Thank You! This sums it up for me and solves my problem @ChrisDodd

Comment: @ChrisDodd I had another doubt related to the same question, so imagine in nfa, i haven't mentioned a transition for "epsilon" for a particular state, which automatically would imply that if that state decides to use the "epsilon" that is the empty transition, it would go to a "dead / trap" state. Since this is NFA this particular branch of computation would then die and it will move onto other possibilities

Is my logical understanding correct?

Comment: Also, that "dead / trap" state would again have a transition to itself for all the alphabet symbols +"epsilon"

Comment: Yes, or you can just freely delete any NFA state that can't lead to any accepting state without any loss of correctness.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much :) you explain very well @ChrisDodd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one with Ø. Consider a simple NFA:

```
  /-> S -a-> (T)
  |   |
  \-a-/
```

S is the start state, T is an accepting state. The alphabet is {a, b}.

When this machine reads the string `b`, it rejects. If the transition set for (S, b) were {S}, then the DFA this converts into would accept `ba`, which is obviously wrong.

The right transition states are as follows:

```
S, a, {S, T}
S, b, Ø
{S, T}, a, {S, T}
{S, T}, b, Ø
Ø, a, Ø
Ø, b, Ø
```

And you could draw this DFA in two ways. A incomplete DFA (where the null state is omitted) or a complete DFA (where the null state is present as an inescapable state). `q1 = {S}`, the start state, and `q2 = {S, T}`, the accepting state.

```
Incomplete:
q1 -a-> (q2)<-\
          |   |
          \-a-/

Complete:

    /a,b\
   |    /
    \  v
 /-> q3 <-\
 b        b
 |        |
q1 -a-> (q2)<-\
          |   |
          \-a-/
```

Note that in the complete version, `q3` has the same properties as Ø.

(In general an incomplete DFA can always be replaced with a complete DFA in this manner: create a new non-accepting state `d`, whose outgoing transitions are `d, Σ, d`, and whose incoming transitions are whatever transitions are missing from the original DFA. `d` is the "dump" state, and can be thought of as a "rejecting" state as opposed to an accepting state. As soon as an input leads into that state, it has no path to acceptance and so can be rejected.)

Comment: Thank for explaining, the first example seemed to change my perspective and i finally understand it